# Where does Gnome Evolution save the "NSS Certificate" password?

Tags: security, gnome, certificate, evolution, gnome-keyring

I'm using Evolution 3.44.3 on Fedora 36.

I got a certificate (PKCS12 file) to digitally sign mails I send. The certificate file is secured by a password. When I imported the certificate into Evolution, I must have entered the file password into a wrong prompt because I ended up entering the password multiple times.

Now, every time I try to sign an email, I am presented with the following prompt:
[image: prompt asking for "NSS User Private Key and Certificate Services"]

To satisfy this prompt and send my signed mail, I need to re-enter the password of my PKCS12 file. [This exchange](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/evolution-list/2014-November/msg00122.html) suggests that this should not be the case if my "default key" was the same as my login password.

I tried to reset the password the weird prompt asks for by 1) un- and reinstalling evolution, 2) deleting all `evolution/` directories I found in my home directory and 3) clearing the Gnome keyring by deleting `~/.local/share/keyrings/`. None of that worked and the prompt still expects the certificate file password.

I am convinced that something is wrong with this prompt, because when I try to import a new certificate in Evolution, I have to first enter the password of the old certificate file into this prompt and only after that I am prompted for the password of the actual file I am trying to import.

Where is the "password for 'NSS User Private Key and Certificate Services', token 'NSS Certificate DB'" saved and how do I reset it to my login password so that I can properly send signed mails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password isn't for your PKCS#12 file, but for the whole private-key database.

Evolution uses NSS for certificate storage, with the database located at `~/.pki/nssdb/` – which is also shared with Epiphany and Chrome/Chromium. (This is also the same certificate management system as in Firefox, Thunderbird, or SeaMonkey, though those apps use isolated NSS databases in their 'profile' directories.)

You can change the password using `certutil -d "sql:$HOME/.pki/nssdb" -W`. It is completely unrelated to gnome-keyring or to your login password. (The mailing list post refers to a very old version of gnome-keyring; its PKCS#11 key storage capabilities have been since ripped out completely, and Evolution now only uses the standard NSS 'softtoken' module.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! For me the database was at `~/.local/share/pki/nssdb`. Does that mean in consequence that I will always have to enter the NSS password to send a signed mail?

Comment: You should be able to completely remove the password if you want to; I don't remember any NSS apps trying to enforce one previously. (There's no option to have it stored in gnome-keyring, however – if you keep the password then you'll have to enter it every time. I'd suggest removing it and relying on LUKS/fscrypt/eCryptFS instead.)